# /sys is mounted read-only and this stops my laptop from suspending to RAM

Tags: mount, suspend

My laptop has recently started to fail to suspend to RAM from time to time. I've completely re-installed Kubuntu 14.04 (trusty), but the error comes back intermittently.

Looking at `/var/log/pm-powersave.log` I see entries like this:

```
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices false:
Setting Host Bridge 0000:00:00.0 to on
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices: 30: /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices: cannot create /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/powe
r/control: Read-only file system
Setting Ethernet device 0000:00:19.0 to on
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices: 18: /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices: cannot create /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:19.0/powe
r/control: Read-only file system
Setting Audio device 0000:00:1b.0 to on
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices: 26: /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices: cannot create /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1b.0/powe
r/control: Read-only file system
Setting card reader device 0000:02:00.0 to on
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices: 38: /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices: cannot create /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/powe
r/control: Read-only file system
Setting Wireless device 0000:03:00.0 to on
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices: 22: /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices: cannot create /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/powe
r/control: Read-only file system
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices false: success.
```

`mount` however shows this:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
```

I've not found anything different that I'm running on the machine between when it suspends and when it doesn't. Nothing new has been plugged into it either.

What might be causing it to report a read only sys filesystem? Is there some way that I can try to remount `/sys` so that maybe it will be marked as read/write again?

Comment: Try `sudo mount -o ro,remount /sys; sudo mount -o rw,remount /sys`.

Comment: That worked. Maybe I'll add that line to the first failing script if it keeps happening.